# Tor$_1^R(H_{n-1}(C),A) = 0$ for all $n \geq 0.$

Tags: homological-algebra, spectral-sequences

Corrollary $10.30$ from Rotman's Homological Algebra.

Let $C$ be a positive complex of free $R$ modules. $A$ is a $R$-module, where $R$ is commutative hereditary. There's an exact sequence:

$0\to H_n(C)\otimes A \to H_n(C \otimes A) \to$ Tor$_1^R(H_{n-1}(C),A) \to 0$ for all $n \geq 0.$

In the proof, Rotman tells to apply $10.29$ which I put at the bottom.

I applied and found the corresponding term of Tor$_1^R(H_{n-1}(C),A)$ in the resultant sequence from $10.29$ is zero. So I concluded Tor$_1^R(H_{n-1}(C),A) = 0$ for all $n \geq 0.$

Any help would be appreciated!

Corollary $10.29$

Let M be a first quadrant bicomplex for which $E^2$ consists of two adjacent columns: $E^2_{p,q} = 0$ for all $p \neq 0,1.$ For each n, there is an exact sequence:
$0 \to E^2_{0,n} \to H_n(Tot(M)) \to E^2_{1,n-1} \to 0$.

Comment: Why do you think that's zero?

Comment: That doesn't seem right. You can get any cyclic group as $H_{n-1}(C)$, and these are not flat.

Comment: hey guys! I feel it odd too. Iet me add some details! Adding the details now! Thx for your attention!

Comment: I don't see where in your edit or the original text it suggests $\operatorname{Tor}_1^R(H_{n-1}(C),A)=0$ for all $n\ge 0$. Where are you getting this from? The $E_2$ page has column 0 containing $H_n(C)\otimes_R A$, and column 1 containing the $\operatorname{Tor}_1^R(H_n(C),A)$, and the homology of the total complex (by taking homology in the other order) is that of $C\otimes A$, so we get the result, but I don't see where you get that the tor terms vanish here. Could you perhaps elaborate?

Comment: Dear jgon, I seem to have gotton it now that I am revisiting it after 2 days! Thank you for your hint! It helped!